# How to change the order of the columns by the amount of NA in the column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, na, col

I have a large dataset with multiple rows and columns. I want to change the order of the columns by the amount of missing values in the column so that the variable with the most `NA`s is the first column and the variable with the least `NA`s is the last column.

So far I tried to use `dplyr`'s `select` but did not get what I wanted.

```
df_ordered <- df %>% 
    select(order(is.na(df)))
```

Answer (score 2):

you do:

`df <- df[order(-colSums(apply(df, 2, is.na)))]`

or

`df <- df[order(colSums(apply(df, 2, is.na)), decreasing = T)]`

with dplyr is more verbose:

```
df <- df %>% relocate(
  df %>% summarise(across(everything() , ~sum(is.na(.)))) %>% 
    unlist() %>% order(decreasing=T))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `dplyr` with `colSums`, where we can get the sum of `NA`s in each column, then sort that named numeric vector, then we return the names for the `select` statement.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(names(sort(colSums(is.na(.)), decreasing = TRUE)))
```

**Output**

```
   X10 X5 X6 X1 X2 X3 X4 X8 X9 X7
1   NA  0 NA NA  1 NA NA NA  1 NA
2   NA  1 NA NA  0  1  0  1 NA  0
3    0 NA NA  1 NA  1  1  1  0  1
4   NA NA  1  0  1  0  1 NA NA  1
5   NA NA  0 NA  0  0  0  1  0  1
6    1 NA NA  1  0 NA  1  0  1  1
7    1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1
8   NA  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0
9   NA NA  0  0 NA  0  0  1  1  0
10  NA  1 NA  0  0  0 NA  1  0  1
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(NA, NA, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
    X2 = c(1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L), X3 = c(NA, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X4 = c(NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA), X5 = c(0L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 
    0L, NA, 1L), X6 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, NA
    ), X7 = c(NA, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), X8 = c(NA, 
    1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X9 = c(1L, NA, 0L, NA, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), X10 = c(NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, 1L, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is on the right track, but you need to map across columns, and use `mean` (or `sum`) to collapse each column to a single number.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat <- data.frame(
  x2 = c(1, NA, 2, NA),
  x3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 4),
  x1 = c(1, 2, NA, 4)
)

dat %>%
  select(rev(order(map_dbl(., ~ mean(is.na(.x))))))
```

```
  x3 x2 x1
1 NA  1  1
2 NA NA  2
3 NA  2 NA
4  4 NA  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on answer from Ric Villalba going for brevity in base R and {dplyr}:

```r
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:5, NA), 49, T, prob = c(rep(1, 5), 5)), ncol = 7))

# base R
d[,order(-colSums(is.na(d)))]
#>   X4 X2 X5 X1 X3 X6 X7
#> 1 NA  4  2 NA  5  4  5
#> 2  4  4 NA NA NA  5  3
#> 3 NA NA NA  3  5 NA  3
#> 4 NA NA  3  1  1  5  5
#> 5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#> 6 NA  4 NA  2  5  2 NA
#> 7 NA NA  2  1  1  4  5

# with tidyverse
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  select(order(-colSums(is.na(.))))
#>   X4 X2 X5 X1 X3 X6 X7
#> 1 NA  4  2 NA  5  4  5
#> 2  4  4 NA NA NA  5  3
#> 3 NA NA NA  3  5 NA  3
#> 4 NA NA  3  1  1  5  5
#> 5 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#> 6 NA  4 NA  2  5  2 NA
#> 7 NA NA  2  1  1  4  5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>